# copy single/multiple records from a query and update the same in the queried table

Tags: t-sql

Ok, I have a query that will bring 1 or more records I know how to update but I need to insert the same  PN and Keyvalue to a temp table so I can revert my update at a later time.

I could create a table var and put the records in it then update from the table var and do my insert from the table var.

Is that the most efficient method?

Comment: I feel like you need to better explain the problem here, if I am honest. If you need to be able to revert the changes, why are you not using tranasctions?

Comment: I will be doing the revert at a later time 30 min.

Comment: This really smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), if I am honest.

Comment: Also T-SQL is a dialect used by several products such as (but not limited to)  Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What data engine are you using here?

Comment: [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess) that might be related: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows. `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`.

Answer (score -2):

```
declare @tempTable table(PART nvarchar(30), [ENTDATE] [datetime])
declare @entdate datetime
set @entdate = getdate()

insert into @tempTable(PIW_PART, PIW_ENTDATE)
select mfgp.part, @entdate from [dbo].[PARTMFGS] mfgp
inner join PARTS p on mfgp.MFP_PART = par_code
where mfgp.MFP_MANUFACTPART = 'ddd1' and mfgp.MFP_MANUFACTURER = 'udy'
and (PREVENTREORDERS = '+')

update rp
set PREVENTREORDERS  = '-',
UPDATED = getdate(),
UPDATEDBY = 'IONUSER'
from PARTS rp
inner join @tempTable tt on tt.PART collate Latin1_General_BIN = code

--@tempTable
insert into PARTS_temp (PIW_PART, PIW_ENTDATE)
select * from @tempTable
```

Comment: What is this meant to be, your answer to the question? Can you add details on why this is the answer you came to? Why do you have table variables called `@temptable`? Table variables *aren't* temporary tables and behave **very** differently.